# Find $x$ from ln with two equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to solve the following

$y = f(x)$

$y = \ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) $

I need to find $x$.

It is ruining my life for the past 30 minutes ... and i am sure it is really easy

Thank you in advance

Comment: I formatted your question. I assume you meant $\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ and not $\ln(1+\frac x1-x)$ or $\ln(1+\frac x{1-x})$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen correct, thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\frac2{1-x}-1$.

Comment: What is $f$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by definition of logarithm,
$$
\frac{1+x}{1-x} = e^y,
$$
or
$$
1+x=(1-x)e^y.
$$
Hence
$$
(1+e^y)x=e^y-1,
$$
that is
$$
x = \frac{e^y-1}{e^y+1}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not get it.Could you explain it a little bit more? thanks

Comment: @Chris Are you familiar with exponentiation? $y=\ln x\iff e^y=x$

Comment: i figured it out a few minutes ago . Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

AS $y=\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}$, by exponential map, we can get that $e^{y}=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$, then $x=\frac{e^{y}-1}{e^{y}+1}$.